# Multiple domains on Amazon AWS EC2

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am a bit confused on how I can use Amazon AWS to host multiple websites. I under stand how to host a website on there however I am only allowed up to 5 elastic ip addresses. So how would I host more than 5 domains if I cannot assign an ip address to each domain? I could use the Amazon Public DNS address provided which is something like (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com) however I cannot use this as a A record when it comes to changing the domain's DNS.

Help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need one elastic IP address. The rest can be achieved using [**name based virtual hosting**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html).

- Create an **[A record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types)** that points to your elastic IP address for your main host.
- Create a [**CNAME**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) record for each of the additional domains that you want that points to you main domain name A record.
- Create a virtual host for each domain.

Comment: So that means I have to put all the web files on one instance? Won't that mean that each domain will share the same resources? - slowing down the server?

Comment: @John: Depending on what your domains are doing, many domains can be hosted on a single instance. When you need to scale above one instance then you should assess what needs to be scaled and take appropriate action.

Comment: @Iain, Can you elaborate on step 2? Would that be in `GoDaddy` for example? What would be example values for `host` and `points to`? Also, what should be the value of the `A record` on the second domain?

Comment: @mgPePe http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPIPDomainNameSystemDNS.htm

Answer (score 1):

For web sites, the only time you absolutely need multiple IP's is when you're doing SSL (HTTPS) for multiple sites.

Answer (score 0):

1. Point all your sites to a single IP address.
2. Using your web server, create virtual hosts. This means the web server resolve your site based on the name of the site.

What web server are you running?