# Help adding CNAME to main host for Amazon EC2 (route 54)

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, domain, amazon-web-services

I am trying to accomplish what is answered in this thread [Multiple domains on Amazon AWS EC2](https://serverfault.com/questions/301276/multiple-domains-on-amazon-aws-ec2)

I am trying to "Create a CNAME record for each of the additional domains that you want that points to you main domain name A record."

When I do this I get this error:

RRSet with DNS name mydomain1.com. is not permitted in zone mydomain0.com.

Do I have to create a new host zone for every single domain that I have? I hope not... Please help.

Comment: Not to nit pick, but it's Route 53.  And yes you need one zone per domain.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a zone file for every DNS domain name. The CNAME entry has to be put in the mydomain1.com zone file and it should be pointed to mydomain0.com.

Now, mydomain0.com should have a zone file one some DNS name server where it has a A record pointing to a IP address...